# Cassandra Max Count SubString

Tags: cql, cassandra-2.0, nosql-aggregation

Need to do some Max Count Groupby and substring (like a%) kind of queries. currently using Cassandra 2.1 (DataStax 4.8).

I need to do queries like - how much a product sold on a specific day, which product sold maximum on a specific day, how many product-ids start with 'A', etc.

Based on my understanding is is not not feasible with C*2. So my choices are C*3 and UDF or use Sparks - is that correct. 
Getting into Sparks is of course a big challenge, and upgrade C*3 and UDF learning also an additional challenge.

If someone could suggest path of least resitance,

Thx